# Class of languages recognizable by n-bit formulas of size at most $T(n)$

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, satisfiability, complexity-classes, circuits

A Boolean (combinatoiral) **circuit** is a labeled (with the labels: AND, OR, NOT, IN, OUT), directed, acyclic graph, that satisfies:

1. fan-in=2 for the AND and OR nodes
2. fan-n=1 for the NOT nodes
3. fan-in=0 for the IN nodes
4. fan-out=0 to exactly one node (the OUT node)
5. Unbounded fan-out to the rest of the nodes (but the OUT node)

A Boolean **formula** is a Boolean circuits with fan-out $\leq$ 1 to all of the nodes.

Let us denote by $C(T(n))$ the class of all languages recognizable by n-bit **formulas** of size (in the meaning of Boolean circutit size) at most T(n).

Let us denote by $\text{Size}(T(n))$ the class of all languages recognizable by n-bit Boolean **circuits** of size at most $T(n)$.

1. What is the relationship between $C(T(n))$ and $\text{Size}(T(n))$?
2. Is $C(T(n))$ a well-known class? What is its name in the literature?

Comment: Functions computed by polysize formulas constitute the well-known class NC$^1$.